# git: find where a line is moved in newer source file

Tags: git

I've viewed [A Whole New World](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/a-whole-new-world) talk by [Gary Bernhardt](https://twitter.com/garybernhardt) and one function he described in his fictional editor would be very helpful.

Given a production software crashing and producing a stacktrace/traceback such as

> ```
> undefined local variable or method `tweet_id' (NameError)
> /Users/grb/proj/toot/database.rb:40:in `tweet_key'
> /Users/grb/proj/toot/database.rb:33:in `tweet'
> ```

his editor can *fast-forward* to locate the possible line location in current code source.

It's useful because code in production is likely older than the current code, and the lines involved in the error messages could have been moved in the file as other lines could have been added or removed above the lines we're interested in. So if we're going to fix the issue in current code, we must first locate the line number in the current code.

Being able to pinpoint the new line location seems like a nice feature to have for large code base.

And I think `git` can do such thing. But I cannot figure what command/option to use.

In particular, `git log -L 40:database.rb` would show what happen previously to the line.

And I want the opposite: given the production *tag*, I want git to search in the future (relative to the *tag*) instead of the past.

Is there a command/option that can be used to *convert* line number in past (production *tag*) to a number in the future (*master*) ?

Comment: `git blame --reverse -C -M` may be a starting point. Internally it does more or less what you're looking for (trace the history of a line from the past to the future), but instead of giving you the right line number, it gives you the last revision in which the line appeared, which is unfortunately not what you want.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427647/7099148) may also help here.

Comment: @user31601 yes `git log -S` (aka git pickaxe) is a powerful tool, but it doesn't address the need I've described

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a feature in Git. However, I believe you could mimic it:

1. Create a branch from the production tag, and check it out.
2. Add an identifying comment to the faulty line of code.
3. Commit to your new branch
4. Merge *master* into your branch.
5. Search for the comment you added (e.g. with `grep`) - it will be at the new location.